# How DateTime.UtcNow value is calculated?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, time, timer

Where exactly .Net is taking this value from? Is this a value from [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx)?
How this value is calculated then? Is it somehow based on [QPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) value?

Comment: My question for you is why it matters where the value comes from.

Comment: It's a call to [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,b0d5e4c9a8d4ddac)

Comment: `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` is `internal`. So..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I need to sync local network machines no 1ms. I am looking to different solutions available and trying to understand where various values are derived and how they relate to each other.

Comment: @Kimi NTP not do you?

Comment: Synching time is a well understood problem that already has solutions. Why aren't you using the standard approaches for this? Why is this even a programming question? It's a sysadmin task.

Comment: As for any .net "how is something written" question - just look at the public source code at the MS reference source website.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the accuracy of DateTime.UtcNow is 16ms. I have a 1ms requirement and unfortunately this becomes a developer problem as well since a different clock is needed.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a classic XY question.

Comment: GetSystemTimeAsFileTime does **not** use QPC but [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) **does**. Your requirement for low granularity timekeeping may be fulfilled with this new function. You may want to read [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: @Arno, I did read that. I am using a Win 2008 server, and GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime is only available on 2012.

Comment: @Kimi I'm with david here. This is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain what is your underlying problem instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UtcNow` is defined as below.(Attributes stripped for brevity)

```
public static DateTime UtcNow
{
    get
    {
        return new DateTime((ulong) ((GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() + 0x701ce1722770000L) | 0x4000000000000000L));
    }
}
```

`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` is defined as internal call.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecurityCritical]
internal static extern long GetSystemTimeAsFileTime();
```

Reflector can't help anymore, lets dig into [sscli](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917).

`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` maps to `SystemNative::__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` (ecall.cpp)

```
FCFuncStart(gDateTimeFuncs)
    FCFuncElement("GetSystemTimeAsFileTime", SystemNative::__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime)
FCFuncEnd()
```

And finally `SystemNative::__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` is implemented as below (comsystem.cpp)

```
FCIMPL0(INT64, SystemNative::__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime)
{
    WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
    STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;

    INT64 timestamp;

    ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime((FILETIME*)&timestamp);

#if BIGENDIAN
    timestamp = (INT64)(((UINT64)timestamp >> 32) | ((UINT64)timestamp << 32));
#endif

    return timestamp;
}
FCIMPLEND;
```

So, `UtcNow` is simply a wrapper around [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and handles the case for [BigEndian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

We can't go further till microsoft releases its open source operating system :)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.UtcNow` is calculated by subtracting the offset of the host operating systems time-zone from the current date/time.

And yes, looking in ILSpy internally it is calling [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
[SecurityCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
internal static extern long GetSystemTimeAsFileTime();
```

To do this manually pull the current time-zone using [TimeZoneInfo.Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local(v=vs.110).aspx), this gives you a [BaseUtcOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can then subtract from the current date/time, for example:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz_info = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
TimeSpan offset = tz_info.BaseUtcOffset;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime utc_now = now.Subtract(offset);
```

Note that these values are stored as operating system settings in the registry and beyond. Remember when you install Windows you choose what time-zone you want to be in. If you are brave you can find some of the information here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`

There's an excellent article on time-zones etc on MSDN Blogs - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx

Comment: I don't think the asker wants to know how the time zone conversion is performed.

Comment: Indeed, I am interested in how the actual value is derived.

Comment: IlSpy? Did it ever occur to you to just look at the source code?

Comment: @TomTom Did it occur to you I might not have it available?

Comment: @Lloys Yeah. You know it is on the internet? Check my answer. MS made it public years ago. Can you please define "not available" given that all you need to do is to head over to the reference source website?

Comment: Ignorance. No worry, you are not alone. Most people today seem to think that not knowing what they do is professional.

Comment: @TomTom I didn't mean I didn't know. I meant I didn't go over to the site. You've no idea where I am or what I have access to to make sweeping assumptions. But you're trolling so whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Whow. People checking IL instead of the source code.

The source of the DateTime class is at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b

UtcNow starts at line 959.

No need to use disassembler, reflector or anything else - you can see the code as it was written.

Comment: But nothing is implemented in managed code. So, checking the source also doesn't provide much insight.